# Spark SQL read a JSON file which has already escaped double quote

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a simple Spark Program which reads a JSON file and emits a CSV file. In the JSON file data is escaped for double quote. The spark program is not able to read the line as a valid JSON string.

input.json

```
{\"key\" : \"k1\", \"value1\": \"Good String\", \"value2\": \"Good String\"}
```

input_1.json

```
"{\"key\" : \"k1\", \"value1\": \"Good String\", \"value2\": \"Good String\"}"
```

output.csv - the data is coming back as corrupt record

```
_corrupt_record,key,value1,value2
"{\\"key\\\" : \\\"k1\\\", \\\"value1\\\": \\\"Good String\\\", \\\"value2\\\": \\\"Good String\\\"}",,,
```

expected.csv

```
,k1,Good String,Good String
```

Please look at the main code below and advise

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName(TestSpark.class.getName()).master("local[1]").getOrCreate();

    SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
    context.setLogLevel("ERROR");
    SQLContext sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext();

    List<StructField> kvFields = new ArrayList<>();
    kvFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("_corrupt_record", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    kvFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("key", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    kvFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("value1", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    kvFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("value2", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    StructType employeeSchema = DataTypes.createStructType(kvFields);

    Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read()
                    .option("inferSchema", false)
                    .format("json")
                    .schema(employeeSchema)
                    .load("D:\\dev\\workspace\\java\\simple-kafka\\key_value.json");

    dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("sourceView");
    sqlCtx.sql("select * from sourceView")
            .write()
            .option("header", true)
            .format("csv")
            .save("D:\\dev\\workspace\\java\\simple-kafka\\output\\" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    sparkSession.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the as text and parse manually. I don't use Spark with Java but here is the Scala equivalent, which you can use as pseudocode:

```
val rdd: RDD[MyClass] = sc.textFile(path)
  .map { line =>
    val json = ... // turn line into valid json
    Try(parse(json))
      .recover {
        case NonFatal(ex) => // handle parse error
      }
      .map { jvalue =>
        // Convert the JSON into a case class
      }
      .get
  }

val ds: Dataset[MyClass] = spark.createDataset(rdd)
```